# C++ Missing elements when inserting a vector of pairs into an unordered_map

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, memory-management, stl

I have the following aliases

```
/**
 * @typedef PixelPos
 * @brief   Coordinates of pixel position
*/
using PixelPos = pair<int, int>; /// (row,column)
using ContextTableBase = unordered_map< PixelPos, vector<PixelPos> >; /// (hash(px), list of neighbours)
```

For convenience, instead of using directly the unordered_map, in order to retain information neccessary to implement the hash function, a new child class is defined.

```
class ContextTable : public ContextTableBase
{
///... definition of operators and constructor ...
               return ContextTableBase::operator[]( PixelPos{ oPixel.first * (height - (height-width)), oPixel.second } );
}
```

And the hash function employed is

```
template<> struct hash<PixelPos>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(PixelPos const& pixel) const noexcept
        {
            return pixel.first + pixel.second; /// mapped row + col
        }
    };
```

Inside a function called *getLocalContext*, for each pixel of a square image, represented by a PixelPos (arranged by row and column -both integers- ), I look up some neighbours using a function *applyMask*, which is shown bellow.

```
/**
 * @brief Función local para aplicar la mascara del contexto local a cada uno de los pixeles
 * @param oPosition [in] - px location
 * @param oMask [in] - context mask
 * @param width [in] - number of columns of the image
 * @param height [in] - number of rows of the image
 * @param oRet [out] - Return list
 * @returns oRet
*/
static void applyMask(const PixelPos& oPosition, const ContextMask& oMask, const int width, const int height, vector<PixelPos>& oRet)
{
    for(const auto& dot : oMask )
    {
        PixelPos oCandidate{ oPosition.first + dot.first, oPosition.second + dot.second };
/// ... do something to check if candidate is neighbour...
            oRet.push_back(oCandidate);
/// ... do something else ...
    }
}

/// ... more code ...

/**
 * @brief Context calculator
 * @param N [in] - Context size
 * @param width [in] - number of columns of the image
 * @param height [in] - number of row of the image
 * @returns oTable, hash table which entries are pxs and returns a list of neighbours
*/
ContextTable& getLocalContext(const size_t N, const int width, const int height)
{

    ContextTable oTable = new ContextTable(height, width);
    ContextMask oMask{ createPixelMask(N) };

    for(int row = 0; row < height; ++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < width; ++col)
        {

            PixelPos oPosition{ row, col };
            if( oTable.find(oPosition) == oTable.end() )
            {
                vector<PixelPos> oNeighbours{};
                applyMask(oPosition, oMask, width, height, oNeighbours);
                oTable.insert(make_pair(oPosition, oNeighbours));
            }
                

        }
    }
  return (*oTable);
}
```

The vector returned by this functions is correct and have exactly the pixels I was looking for, but after adding it to oTable, before leaving *getLocalContext*, the entries to the pixels bellow the first row are lost.

As an example, an output of the problem is show for a image of size 5x4 (rows, columns)

The correct values to be inserted in oTable (taken from the oNeighbours after each call to applyMask) are

```
applyMask px central: r: 0| c: 0
applyMask px central: r: 0| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 0
applyMask px central: r: 0| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 0
applyMask px central: r: 0| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 1| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 1| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 2
applyMask px central: r: 1| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 0
applyMask px central: r: 1| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 0| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 2| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 2| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 2
applyMask px central: r: 2| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 0
applyMask px central: r: 2| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 1| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 3| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 3| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 2
applyMask px central: r: 3| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 0
applyMask px central: r: 3| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 2| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 4| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 1
applyMask px central: r: 4| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 4| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 0
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 2
applyMask px central: r: 4| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 4| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 1
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 4| c: 0
applyMask px central: r: 4| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 4| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 3
applyMask    n: r: 3| c: 2
applyMask    n: r: 4| c: 1
```

However, the actual values stored (taken from oTable before returning from getLocalContext) are

```
 px central: r: 0| c: 0
 px central: r: 0| c: 1
     n: r: 0| c: 0
 px central: r: 0| c: 2
     n: r: 0| c: 1
     n: r: 0| c: 0
 px central: r: 0| c: 3
     n: r: 0| c: 2
     n: r: 0| c: 1
 px central: r: 1| c: 0
     n: r: 3| c: 0
     n: r: 3| c: 1
 px central: r: 1| c: 1
     n: r: 4| c: 0
     n: r: 3| c: 1
     n: r: 3| c: 0
     n: r: 3| c: 2
 px central: r: 1| c: 2
     n: r: 4| c: 1
     n: r: 3| c: 2
     n: r: 3| c: 1
     n: r: 3| c: 3
     n: r: 4| c: 0
 px central: r: 1| c: 3
     n: r: 4| c: 2
     n: r: 3| c: 3
     n: r: 3| c: 2
     n: r: 4| c: 1
 px central: r: 2| c: 0
 px central: r: 2| c: 1
 px central: r: 2| c: 2
 px central: r: 2| c: 3
 px central: r: 3| c: 0
 px central: r: 3| c: 1
 px central: r: 3| c: 2
 px central: r: 3| c: 3
 px central: r: 4| c: 0
 px central: r: 4| c: 1
 px central: r: 4| c: 2
 px central: r: 4| c: 3
```

Comment: `(height - (height-width))` equals `width`. Did you mean it this way? It looks odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem after realizing that the find and insert methods of unordered_map were not overriden, thus the wrong version of the hash function was being called.

The applied change on *getLocalContext* was

```
       PixelPos oMappedPosition{ row * (height - (height-width)), col };
       if( oTable.find(oMappedPosition) == oTable.end() )
       {
         vector<PixelPos> oNeighbours{};
         applyMask(PixelPos{row, col}, oMask, width, height, oNeighbours);
         oTable.insert(make_pair(oMappedPosition, oNeighbours));
       }
```

Comment: Mark as answered